# How to download multiple CSV files off a website using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I am a beginner at programming (Finance professional) & I am looking to cut manual work using Python. I want to download multiple CSVs (Daily Volatility CSVs of past one year) from https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm

So far, I am able to download one file at a time. But I am not able to apply for loop to download past one year's CSVs. Also, it would help if I can skip downloading CSVs from Saturdays and Sundays.

I made a csv file where links to all required CSV files are mentioned. Then tried to import that csv file and run a for loop operation on it. But I don't know enough programming to do that.

```py
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/volt/CMVOLT_01072018.CSV', stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("01072018.csv", 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Desired results: Download CSV files based on a date range input.
Actual results: Downloading 1 CSV file at a time.

Comment: I'm confused by the "expected results".  This code does not contain a loop, so how could you expect it to download more than one file?  Did you mean to say _Desired_ results?

Comment: I deleted that part of the code as it didn't work. I mentioned that to give idea about my thought process. And yes, it should be desired results.

Answer (score 1):

```
filenames=['https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/volt/CMVOLT_01072018.CSV',
'https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/volt/CMVOLT_01082018.CSV',
'https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/volt/CMVOLT_01092018.CSV',
]

for x in filenames:
    r=requests.get(x, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(x.split('_')[-1], 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright without adding another library, the following is the code which should work even though it didn't work on my machine which has some restrictions.

```
import datetime as timer
import requests
import shutil


def download_data(date):
    url='https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/volt/CMVOLT_'+date+'.CSV'
    csv_filename=date+'.csv'
    try:
        print('Calling url:- ' + url)
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True,verify=False)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(csv_filename, 'wb') as f:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
        r.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print('for Date '+ date +' Exception happened, most probably a weekend, EXCEPTION Message is ' + str(e))



def code_runner():
    i=0
    now = timer.datetime.now()
    day = now.day
    month = now.month
    year = now.year
    while i<365:
        day=day-1
        if day==0:
            day=31
            month=month-1
            if month==0:
                month=12
                year=year-1
        year1=year
        month1='{:02d}'.format(month)
        day1='{:02d}'.format(day)
        date=str(day1)+str(month1)+str(year1)
        download_data(date)
        i+=1

if __name__=='__main__':
    code_runner()
```

Comment: I keep getting exception:
 EXCEPTION Message is HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nseindia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /archives/nsccl/volt/CMVOLT_22072019.CSV (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003B2CCC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

I think it cause my machine is in restricted environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a date loop for your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# --------------------
import requests
import shutil
import datetime
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dates=[datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(dval) for dval in range(0,366)];
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for dateval in dates:
    r = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/volt/CMVOLT_'+dateval.strftime('%d%m%Y')+'.CSV', stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(dateval.strftime('%d%m%Y')+".csv", 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.